# i try to do make project but its writes me this error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, runtime-error

Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Cannot resolve external dependency androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0 because no repositories are defined.
> Required by:
> project :app
> Cannot resolve external dependency com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0 because no repositories are defined.
> Required by:
> project :app
> Cannot resolve external dependency androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2 because no repositories are defined.
> Required by:
> project :app

Answer (score 0):

Add `google()` inside `repositories` of your project level `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()

    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

And make sure, offline mode is not turned for Gradle, from the Gradle sidebar menu on the right

[image]

Comment: i try and dont work